# Carl Fredricksen hat. What is meant by "upvote"?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

The [description](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/carl-fredricksen) of the hat states:

> at least 5 upvotes from 5 different users in a UTC day with no downvotes

What kind of *upvotes* are we talking about? For example, are comments upvotes taken into account? And what would happen if I get 5 upvotes in comments but a downvote in a question/answer?

Comment: @downvoter Why a downvote? Please, post a suggestion or at least a complain!

Comment: Are there downvotes on comments?

Comment: @Oded Is this a question? Or do you pretend it's an answer?

Comment: I am asking you. So you can look at the definition of the hat and apply that knowledge.

Comment: @Oded There is no downvote in comments, as far as I know. With this, do you mean that if I get 5 upvotes in questions and a downvote in an answer, they belong to different categories? Will I get the hat in that case?

Comment: My point is - if you can't downvote on comments, why would upvotes on comments be considered for this hat?

Comment: Uh, I didn't expect this one. "What is meant by **upvote**"

Comment: @Oded Your reasoning is pretty straight. On the other hand, I don't consider silly asking a clarification about that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it means upvotes on posts only: questions or answers.

- Upvote on a post which is a Community Wiki also counts for the hat.
- If a post with a vote is deleted, the vote still counts for the hat, this applies also for a downvote.
- Comment upvotes are not taken into account for this hat.

Comment: Correct. The word "upvote" without any additional context always refers to upvotes on questions and answers.

Comment: thanks @balpha and what about CW? Counts too?

Comment: Yes, CW or not makes no difference in that regard.

Comment: @balpha to make it whole, one last question (I hope) - what if a post you got upvote for has been deleted? Does it still count for the hat? :)

Comment: Yes, but *down*votes on posts that were deleted count *against* the hat as well.

Comment: @balpha What happens if you delete an old post that had both upvotes and downvotes but none on that day? Does that have any effect on the hat, or only on rep?

Comment: @randal'thor I don't see how that would matter if no votes are from today given that that's all the hat is about.

Comment: @balpha OK, thanks. I just wondered, given that it does affect the rep gained/lost today. But now I got the hat, so all is well :-)